# Can't find class when comparing it's functions in another file

Tags: java, collections

I have this line of code:

```
SortedSet<Person> personenArray = new TreeSet<>
(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getWeight()));
```

And I have a class `Person` which has the method `getWeight()` but it tells me that `Person cannot be resolved to a variable` and it can't find the method `getHeight()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To be able to use the syntactic sugar that the two colons represent, you must remove the trailing parentheses of getWeight.

Comment: which jdk you are pointing to?

Comment: This is a typo, it should be `Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getWeight)`, without the parenthesis. Like Jacob said.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for the simple stupid mistake. It solved the problem.